# I need to convert a specially formatted string to an javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to convert a formatted string to a JavaScript multidimensional array.

I've tried `split()` and `push()` functions but neither seem to work. The format should be already right but I can't seem to figure out how to make the string into an array.

Here's the string:

```
[[24297, 'CWCS Sump 002', -121.50842, 38.54798, '2', 'SEWER SUMP'],[8035, 'CWCS Sump 002A (56)', -121.50842, 38.54798, '2A', 'SEWER SUMP'],[9334, 'CWCS Sump 001', -121.5110297, 38.5703431, '1', 'SEWER SUMP']]
```

I just want a JavaScript array that is 3x6 (if I counted that right) from that string. The number of rows will vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good candidate for JSON.parse; however, single quotes should be converted to double quotes before it will work. Being careful for escaped quotes, you can try:

```js
const raw = `[[24297, 'CWCS Sump 002', -121.50842, 38.54798, '2', 'SEWER SUMP'],[8035, 'CWCS Sump 002A (56)', -121.50842, 38.54798, '2A', 'SEWER SUMP'],[9334, 'CWCS Sump 001', -121.5110297, 38.5703431, '1', 'SEWER SUMP']]`;

const res = JSON.parse(raw.replace(/(?<!\\)'/g, `"`));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I can actually write the string however I want - I had chosen that because I was following a google maps example that had that format..  I am formatting the sting from a database result in traditional asp and returning it through an ajax call

Comment: here is the smae string formatted with double quotes on all values: [["24297", "CWCS Sump 002", "-121.50842", "38.54798", "2", "SEWER SUMP"],["8035", "CWCS Sump 002A (56)", "-121.50842", "38.54798", "2A", "SEWER SUMP"]]

Comment: I think this is working now once I double quoted the values.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as:

```
let str = '[[24297, "CWCS Sump 002", -121.50842, 38.54798, "2", "SEWER SUMP"],[8035, "CWCS Sump 002A (56)", -121.50842, 38.54798, "2A", "SEWER SUMP"]]';

let arr = JSON.parse(str);
```

Notice it better to have the `'` around the entire string the `"` around the string inside. Can do that with:

```
str.replace("'", """);
```

Comment: the string is being returned by an ajax call to a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to me It wont be straight forward. You can try like this.

```
let a = "[
    [24297,'CWCS Sump 002',-121.50842, 38.54798,'2','SEWER SUMP'],
    [8035,'CWCS Sump 002A (56)',-121.50842,38.54798,'2A','SEWER SUMP'],
    [9334,'CWCS Sump 001', -121.5110297,38.5703431,'1','SEWER SUMP']
]";
let c= [];

a.replace('[[','').replace(']]','').split('],[').forEach(
    (x)=>{c.push(x.split(','))}
);
//c is the result
```